# Google play services Problems

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm developing an Android app for a foreign client and this app must provide for the user a direct access to Google play Magazine to buy Magazines, the problem is that Google play Magazines is not available in my country and i have to run tests before publishing the app in Google play store.

so how can i have access to this Magazines store from my country and this access is only for testing not for buying Magazines

Comment: contact support team of google.play

Answer (score 0):

Your client should provide you with a limited VPN access under these circumstances, such that you can access their intranet only to get Internet access via their gateway.

As an alternative, you can use some proxy service where your request appears as that of a gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Install **SuperSU** on your mobile phone, it can give access to all google play content even if it is not allowed in your country. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu&hl=en

Your phone needs to be **ROOTED**.

Look here to find your mobile root instructions: http://forum.xda-developers.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new proxy (some examples here -> http://www.free-proxy.fr/).
The idea is to convince Google that you are in the United States for example.

With that solution there is no need to be root

Answer (score 0):

you can use this web site http://www.serversproxy.net/ is very useful. You can unblock popular sites such as YouTube, Facebook, MySpace, and many other sites.